# Does Azure automatically replicate exiting objects when when storage redundancy type is changed?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Does Azure automatically replicate existing blobs when we change the storage redundancy type from say LRS to ZRS/GRS? or do we have to manually replicate these objects? I know AWS does not auto replicate so i want to know if same applies to Azure as we need to implement that in one of our existing solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not automatic, after you change the storage redundancy type, you need to either perform a manual migration or request that Microsoft performs a live migration.

For details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/redundancy-migration?tabs=portal